# I am not to run command in run console in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vlc, ubuntu-20.04

Actually I am trying to set up a startup wallpaper with sound so I used

```
cvlc --video-wallpaper ~/Downloads/iron%20man.mp4
```

this command in startup

[Startup application window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd9KA.png)

but it's not working. I also tried to run it using **run a command** but it's not working
although when I tried to run using terminal, it's working properly

[This is what I am getting from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTMCQ.png)

I am completely noob, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

That startup GUI likely wants an app *without parameters*.
You could save your command as a `.sh` [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) script, then run it in there.

```
#! /bin/bash

cvlc --video-wallpaper ~/Downloads/iron%20man.mp4
```

Just save it in your `~/Documents/` directory as `animated.sh`
Then set the execute bit on it, so it'll run. `chmod +x animated.sh`

Now use that command  `~/Documents/animated.sh`  in your startup list.